# Powershell regex to capture string after new line

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm having the hardest time with this regex capture. basically, I've imported a csv, where the script reads the text in a column and captures a string within the text, placing it into a variable.
the problem that I'm having is that the capture is also capturing the carriage return. How do i not capture the carriage return?

for example, the text reads:

```
check the following key:
HKLM:\Software\yadda\yadda
```

code:

```
if($file.col2 -match "following key:(?<path>\s*(\S+\s*\S+))"){
  $Matches['path']
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your two line string is placed in `$InStuff` via something like `Get-Content -Path $FullFileName -Raw`, you can use the `(?m)` multiline regex option and a named capture group to put the path into `$Matches.Path` like this ...

```
$InStuff = @'
check the following key:
HKLM:\Software\yadda\yadda
'@

$Null = $InStuff -match '(?m)(?<Path>.+:\\.+)$'
$Path = $Matches.Path

$Path
```

output = `HKLM:\Software\yadda\yadda`

Comment: Lee_Dailey, will this work with a csv? I'm running a foreach loop as this a csv with about 2k lines.

Comment: @light270 - well ... it should. i didn't test that since you didn't mention it. [*grin*] the regex pattern is going to work in any dotnet/PoSh setup, so simply put it where your code needs it.

Comment: thanks. you sent me on the right path. after reviewing and playing with all the regex i was capturing carriage returns with the HKLM line. I'm still not sure if this is the best way but i found this worked: "(?ms)(?<path>.*)(\s)"

Comment: @light270 - kool! i am glad to have helped ... and that you got it working  as you needed it to work! [*grin*]